# Ruby Ternary If Bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

What I'm trying to do is print `Pending Quotes` if the count is `0` or `>1` and `Pending Quote` if the count `==1` but if the `count` is `>1`, the output is `2 true`, the other two cases work fine though and I can't see anything obvious.

```
<%= @pending.nil? ? '0' : @pending.count %>
<%= (!@pending.nil? and @pending.count > 1) or (!@pending.nil? and @pending.count == 0) ? 'Pending Quotes' : 'Pending Quote' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write this way :

```
((!@pending.nil? and @pending.count > 1) or (!@pending.nil? and @pending.count == 0)) ? 'Pending Quotes' : 'Pending Quote'
```

You could also write it as

```
(!@pending.nil? && (@pending.count > 1 || @pending.count == 0)) ? 'Pending Quotes' : 'Pending Quote'
```

Comment: ah, feel silly now. Thanks, will mark it accepted when SO allows me :)

Comment: note: in Ruby is idiomatic to use `&&` `||` for boolean expresions. Use `and` `or` for flow control. Also, it may be worth noting to OP that "!x.nil?" is usually better as simply "x".

Comment: @tokland i agree with you

Answer (score 5):

I'd use the [`pluralize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize) helper:

```
<%= pluralize(@pending, 'Pending Quote') %>
```

Comment: I don't know a bit of ROR.. so I sticked to Ruby only.. :)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)...

```
@pending.try(:count) == 1 ? 'Pending Quote' : 'Pending Quotes'
```

Comment: thanks, that's a very neat way to put it